# update-manager & update-manager-core

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, updates

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
Calculating upgrade... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,258 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

dpkg: error processing package update-manager-core (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
update-manager depends on update-manager-core (= 1:0.196.13); however:
Package update-manager-core is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I believe you are in need of Braiams answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/403187/installarchives-failed-dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-pa

Comment: I've tried it but the same problem accured......
sudo dpkg -r update-manager-core update-manager
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After around two hours of searching I found that I have to run those 2 commands..

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager-core
sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager
```

Comment: Please select your own answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark on the left of this answer so that the issue can be marked as solved..