# Apt-get issues, can't install anything

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I have been trying to install some software packages but I keep getting errors to do with `linux-generic` and `linux-image-generic`.

When running `apt-get -f install` this is the output, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-image-generic
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 322 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,344 B of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.84.98); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.84.98); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 3.2.0.126.141.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
No apport 
report written because MaxReports has already been reached
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

fkraiem the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-image-generic` is:

```
  linux-generic:
      Installed: 3.2.0.84.98
      Candidate: 3.2.0.126.141
      Version table:
         3.2.0.126.141 0
            500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     *** 3.2.0.84.98 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         3.2.0.23.25 0
            500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
    linux-image-generic:
      Installed: 3.2.0.84.98
      Candidate: 3.2.0.126.141
      Version table:
         3.2.0.126.141 0
            500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     *** 3.2.0.84.98 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         3.2.0.23.25 0
            500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Elder Geek the ouput of `dpkg --configure -a` is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
     linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic; however:
      Package linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic is not installed.
    dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
     linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.84.98); however:
      Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
     linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.84.98); however:
      Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 3.2.0.126.141.
    dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-generic
     linux-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-image-generic`.

Comment: what happens if you run `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: See the following link:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/403187/installarchives-failed-dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-pa

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of "package"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403187/installarchives-failed-dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-pa)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar dependency issues on RHEL systems when the kernel and linux-firmware packages are out of date. Have you recently updated/upgraded your Ubuntu install? If not,

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

should suffice to get your system up to date; once that has run through, restart your system and try the install again.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from [Noisy_Botnet](https://askubuntu.com/users/667872/noisy-botnet)'s [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403187/installarchives-failed-dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-pa) (mentioned in their [comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1418338)) seemed to solve the problem:

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-generic linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```